# Permutation of coefficient with coditions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I have 6 coefficients, (V1,V2,H1,H2,D1,D2). Their permutation is 6! = 720.
But I have a rule: V2 cannot lead V1, H2 cannot lead H1 and D2 cannot lead D1.
For example:

**V2V1**H1H2D1D2 is prohibit.

**V2**H1H2**V1**D1D2 is prohibit.

**V2H2H1V1**D1D2 is prohibit.

But

V1H1H2D1D2V2 is not prohibit.

V1H1D1H2D2V2 is not prohibit.

Where should I start?
or How to solve this problem?

(Permutation)

I am sorry for my English Language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "get rid of half repeatedly" argument is not satisfactory to you, we can approach directly via counting methods.

- Pick the locations occupied by the $V$'s.  $\binom{6}{2}$ choices
- Pick the locations occupied by the $D$'s.  $\binom{4}{2}$ choices
- Pick the locations occupied by the $H$'s.  $\binom{2}{2}$ choices

The real kicker here is *the leftmost for each letter will be the one labeled with a 1* and the rightmost will be the one labeled with a two.

Apply multiplication principle to get the total number of arrangements is $\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}=15\cdot 6\cdot 1 = 90$

In other words, your question is in essence the same as the question of how many arrangements of the letters in the word VVDDHH exist, which we know to be $\binom{6}{2,2,2}=90$

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In half of the permutations $V_2$ is before $V_1$ and in the other half $V_1$ is before $V_2$. Therefore, get rid of half of the solutions, leaving us with $360$.

In half of the permutations $H_2$ is before $H_1$ and in the other half $H_1$ is before $H_2$. Therefore, get rid of half of the solutions, leaving us with $180$.

In half of the permutations $D_2$ is before $D_1$ and in the other half $D_1$ is before $D_2$. Therefore, get rid of half of the solutions, leaving us with $90$.

Comment: I am sorry for my poor knowledge. if you said every case can get rid of half of the solution, then it should be 760/3 or not? Could you please show me theory or equation?

Comment: @JawsMcAvoy At every step, we get rid of half of the solution, so we have $$720/2/2/2=720/8=90$$ There is no equation here. I just divide $720$ by $2$ three times.

Comment: one more thing, If 90 is correct. Then I need the evidence to prove, is it real or not? or if I want to write 90 case, How should I start? 
Thank you in advance.